# I want hide Openfire version from admin and user panel

Tags: java, openfire

I have install openfire latest version , but i want to hide openfire verson and openfire name from  my setup. Is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Openfires Web-UI is based on JSP so the login page is a JSP file which you can edit. Here is a Link to the File on github: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/master/src/web/login.jsp

You have to remove the div on Line 281 - 283.

After this you have to rebuild Openfire. I think this can help you:
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/source-build.html